# Image uploader: why do we need to click twice?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, uploader

If I want to upload an image from my computer, here's what I have to do:

1. Bring up the dialog (Ctrl+G or toolbar button click)
2. Click "choose file" (or hit space)
3. Choose my file using OS-and-browser-dependent dialog
4. But **once I have validated the file in the dialog, I again need to click the “upload” button**.

It seems to me that step #4's extra click is unnecessary: I have already chosen the file, so sure I want to upload it. If I had wanted to cancel, I could have done it in the file selection dialog already (or before opening the dialog, even).

It sounds nothing, but slick UI is made of attention to these little nothings. Can we streamline this a bit more, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While such behavior is pretty common e.g. in an "Open File" dialog of a desktop application, people usually do not expect a form on a website to be submitted right after selecting a file.

Comment: Given that balpha said [tag:status-declined], I'll accept this answer. But, I think it's wrong: design a web interface especially optimized for dummies^Wrandom-actions-users, and you'll get the users you asked for :(

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not completely unnecessary. Do you have any idea how many people there are out there that accidentally click the wrong thing because they were going too fast? Me being one of them, I'd be more frustrated that a) it automatically started uploading the wrong image as soon as I selected it and b) I have to remove that one and start the upload process over again rather than just selecting a file again. Not to mention, now Imgur has a worthless image uploaded that will never get used because I didn't intend to upload it.

Comment: Never store p$rn in the same folder as screenshots! ;)

Comment: Then why do we stop here? Why not yet another confirmation button? *“Hey, you have clicked OK twice already, but could you just click on the ‘I swear I want it’ button below?”*

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: But that was the last folder I had open!!!

Comment: @F'x this can all be "fixed" by allowing drag and drop. (Where it's obvious that once you drop the picture, it's uploaded)

Comment: @F'x: Not everyone clicks on a file and clicks on the Ok button in the dialog. Some people just double click, which is even worse when you have a slow program that continues populating and the file you intended to select moves somewhere else as you're clicking.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd animuson is arguing that people might double click by mistake, so I'm pretty sure someöne will argue that you can drag and drop by mistake…

Comment: `nsfw` tag needed

Comment: @animuson clicking okay, hitting return, double clicking… all those are not really random actions

Comment: @F'x: The problem is, the upload dialog here on-site **doesn't know** what the user has to do in order to select a file on whatever device they're using. If you assume that the user had to confirm on their device, you're leading yourself to trouble. **Always confirm yourself.** My phone doesn't have any sort of confirm. When I attempt to upload, it gives me a list of files, and I tap one.

Comment: @F'x some people (my mother is great example) **always** double click. No mistake, she thinks that's the only way things work.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if we start going down that slope, we should require a confirmation after action on the site… design the web interface especially optimized for dummies^Wrandom-actions-users, and you'll get the users you asked for :(